# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/common/TopicAndPartition

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka

While execution of following command in my code:

```
kafka_streams = [KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zk_settings['QUORUM'], zk_settings['CONSUMERS'][k],
                                              {zk_settings['TOPICS'][0]: zk_settings['NUM_THREADS']})
                           .window(zk_settings['WINDOW_DURATION'], zk_settings['SLIDE_DURATION'])
                 for k in range(len(zk_settings['CONSUMERS']))]
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kafka/common/TopicAndPartition
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2743)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1480)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethodsByNameAndLength(ReflectionEngine.java:365)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:317)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:342)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.common.TopicAndPartition
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 12 more
```

Am I missing something?

I was getting some spark error so I rebuilt the spark error and that lead to this error.

Comment: How do you build and run your application?

Comment: check spell of your class name TopicAndPartition, inside common package.

Comment: @Poonam Agrawal - How did you fix this issue? I'm also facing a same issue like you faced previously.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `--packages` when you submit your code.

```
 ./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.2.0  <DIR>/main.py localhost:9092 test
```

> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html

Comment: Thanks your answer helpful in getting rid of similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

The reason I had this issue too is that the spark-streaming-kafka jar I downloaded was not the **assembly** jar. I solved the issue by doing the following:

1. First download the **assembly** `spark-streaming-kafka...jar` with

   ```
   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11/2.2.0/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.0.jar
   ```

For me, I'm using spark-2.2.0, so try to access the URL https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11 to see the appropriate jar you need to download.

2. Then fetch

   ```
   spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.2.0 --jars /path/to/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.2.0.jar myApp.py
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`classNotFoundException`means when your program **spark-submit** is running
it couldn't find its required class `kafka.common.TopicAndPartition` in the program's running directory.

take a look at usage of the **spark-submit** command:

```
# spark-submit --help
Usage: spark-submit [options] <app jar | python file> [app arguments]
Usage: spark-submit --kill [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit --status [submission ID] --master [spark://...]
Usage: spark-submit run-example [options] example-class [example args]

Options:
  --master MASTER_URL         spark://host:port, mesos://host:port, yarn, or         local.
  --deploy-mode DEPLOY_MODE   Whether to launch the driver program locally     ("client") or
                              on one of the worker machines inside the cluster ("cluster")
                              (Default: client).
  --class CLASS_NAME          Your application's main class (for Java / Scala apps).
  --name NAME                 A name of your application.
  --jars JARS                 Comma-separated list of local jars to include on the driver
                              and executor classpaths.
  --packages                  Comma-separated list of maven coordinates of jars to include
                              on the driver and executor classpaths. Will     search the local
                              maven repo, then maven central and any additional remote
                              repositories given by --repositories. The format for the
                              coordinates should be groupId:artifactId:version.
```

Add --jars option with local jar path of kafka as follows:

`# spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.2.0 --jars /path/to/org.apache.kafka_kafka_2.11-0.8.2.1.jar,/path/to/com.yammer.metrics_metrics-core-2.2.0.jar your_python_script.py` .